# Choose an item from items only one time, then a second time if no more are available

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

For a special reason, I want to whenever I create a new profile, it picks a **unique** random avatar from my *profile_avatars* list. Then when all the avatars have already been linked to a profile one time it starts again. It means that an avatar can be linked to multiple profile.

I use two mySQL table which are *profile_infos* and *profile_avatars*

This is my php code so far which pick a random avatar :

```
$req_avatar  = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM profile_avatars ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$data_avatar = $req_avatar->fetch();
$rand = $data_avatar['avatar_address'];
```

Comment: Why "random", or what do you mean by that?  Why not just use the avatars according to some order?  Will users be able to tell the difference/care?

Comment: if you have access to db, just add flag column (0/1). once you pick an avatar with flag 0 (WHERE flag = 0 in your query), raise (UPDATE table) that flag to 1. if there are no more avatars with 0 flag, reset them all and start over.

Comment: For my case, If I have 10 avatars and make 20 profiles, I need to be sure that each avatars have been used 2 times.

Comment: Instead of a flag, add a usages field to your `profile_avatars` table that you will increment on each use. then your SQL is `Select * from profile_avatars order by usages limit 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work:

profile avatars table:

```
profile_avatars
------------------------------------
id | used_on_rotation | url | title |
-------------------------------------
1  |   0               | .. | ..    |
-------------------------------------
2  |   1               | . .| ..    |
-------------------------------------
...
```

when you registering, find avatar by

```
$bdd->query('SELECT * FROM profile_avatars where used_on_rotation = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
```

1. if you get no results - that means all avatars have been used once already and the loop can be reset by

   `update profile_avatars set used_on_rotation = 0`

and then try to find avatar again

2. if you get a $data_avatar , then run the query

   `update profile_avatars set used_on_rotation = 0 where id = $DATA_AVATAR_ID`